# Self Permission Check

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How do I check if the bot (Self) has permissions to send messages and make it an if statement? Im using discord js and I've seen forums like member.roles.cache has, but none cover the bot itself, so how do I check that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Guild#me](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=me) to get the client's GuildMember object in that guild.

```js
// guild = message.guild or any guild object
if (guild.me.roles.cache.has(...)) {

}
```

**Update:** in Discord.JS V14 you now have to use `guild.members.me`

Answer (score 2):

As Elitezen said, you can get GuildMember object using [Guild#me](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=me) but to check if your bot can send messages for example in guild where the command was executed you have to use this:

```js
if(message.guild.me.permissions.has("SEND_MESSAGES")) { // check if bot has SEND_MESSAGES permission
// your code
}
```